# Show that $\Bbb Q$ is not a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebras

> Show that $\Bbb Q$ is not a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-algebra.

I know that $\Bbb Q$ is not a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-module. From here how can I conclude that $\Bbb Q$ is not a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-algebra?

Please help me in this regard.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The largest prime dividing denominators doesn't increase by addition multiplication, or multiplication by an integer.

Comment: Let's understand the fact in a simpler way. Suppose that the generating set for $\Bbb Q$ is a two elements set containing $\frac {1} {5}$ and $\frac {2} {3}$. Then what will happen?

Comment: My previous comment will happen.

Comment: Would you please be more explicit?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to\mathbb{Q}$ be a ring homomorphism. I claim that $\varphi$ is not surjective.

Let $\varphi(x_k)=a_k/b_k$, for $k=1,\dots,n$. Choose a prime $p$ that does not divide $b_k$, for each $k$. Suppose that $\varphi(f)=1/p$. Denote by $\deg_k(f)$ the degree of $f$ as a polynomial in $x_k$ and let
$$
m=\max_k\deg_k(f)
$$
Then we can write
$$
f(a_1/b_1,\dots,a_n/b_n)=\frac{q}{b_1^m\dots b_n^m}
$$
where $q$ is an integer (prove it). Then from $\varphi(f)=1/p$ we derive
$$
pq=b_1^m\dots b_n^m
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Suppose that $" \phi(f) =1/p"$, what is f here?

Comment: @James $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is a polynomial supposed to satisfy $\varphi(f)=1/p$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If we had $\mathbf Q=\mathbf Z\biggl[\dfrac{m_1}{n_1},\dots,\dfrac{m_k}{n_k} \biggr]$, we could as well write
$$\mathbf Q=\mathbf Z\biggl[\frac1N \biggr],\ \text{where }\;N=\operatorname{lcm}(n_1,\dots,n_k).$$
Consider a prime $p$ *not* dividing $N$. Can $\dfrac1p$ be a polynomial in
$\dfrac 1N$?

Comment: @user26857: Thanks for making my notations consistent!

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $\mathbb Q$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb Z$-module (in this case, $\mathbb Z$-algebra). By the Structure Theorem for modules (in this case, it is the theorem on finitely-generated abelian groups) and the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is torsion free, $\mathbb Q\cong \mathbb Z^r$ for some $r\geq 0$. Let $\varphi:\mathbb Q\rightarrow \mathbb Z^r$ be an isomorphism. Since $\varphi$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism, if $n\in \mathbb Z$ is nonzero, then $\varphi(1)=\varphi\left(n\cdot \frac{1}{n}\right)=n\varphi\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Let $\varphi(1)=(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$. Take $n=\mbox{gcd}(a_1,\ldots,a_r)+1$. Then $\varphi\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\notin\mathbb Z^r$, a contradiction.

Comment: The OP said that knows that Q is not a finitely generated Z-module.