# Show that $K$ has characteristic $> 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, which is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.
Show that $K$ has characteristic $> 0$.
I have this hint but I am not quit sure that I understand it; if $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$, then $\mathbb{Z} \subset K$, then $\Bbb Q \subset K$,
and $K$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb Q$-algebra. Use Zariski's Lemma to show that $K$ is a
finitely generated $\Bbb Q$-module, and then Artin-Tate Lemma to get a contradiction

Comment: What don't you understand about the hint? Following the hint, Artin-Tate would imply that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra. Is that true?

Comment: In fact, every such field must be finite: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148745

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606818/show-that-k-is-a-finite-field) for the same question today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$, then $\mathbb{Z} \subset K$, then $\Bbb Q \subset K$,
and $K$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb Q$-algebra. By Zariski's Lemma $K$ is a
finitely generated $\Bbb Q$-module, and by Artin-Tate Lemma we get that $\mathbb Q$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra, [a contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2757999/show-that-bbb-q-is-not-a-finitely-generated-bbb-z-algebra?r=SearchResults).